# encrypted string does'n't matching with db string

Tags: php, c#-4.0

I have encrypted string from query string which i am decoding.and after decoding i am trying to match with db string but this is not working .Here is my code

```
<?php
require_once("db.php");
$id="";
$emailrole="";
if($_GET){
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = base64_decode($_GET['id']);
    $query = "select * from sfrole where email like('{$id}') LIMIT 1";
    $qryy = mysql_query($query);
    $cnt = mysql_num_rows($qryy);
    if($cnt > 0){
        $emailrole = mysql_fetch_array($qryy);
    }else{
        exit();
    }
    }else{
        exit();
    }
}else{
    exit();
}
?>
```

if use like this

```
$query = "select * from sfrole where email like('malik.adeel@shakarganj.com.pk') LIMIT 1";
```

then it works and if use from variable then it don't returns any thing please help

**Update**

I am Encrypting the String in C# like this which i am using in php

```
Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(emailid))
```

Comment: Well, what does `base64_decode($_GET['id']);` return? What does `$_GET['id']` contain?

Comment: Try to `echo $query` and see what you get ?

Comment: it contains email `malik.adeel@shakarganj.com.pk`

Comment: Yes I got whihc i shown in second query

Comment: `like` with brackets is wrong and will return a mySQL syntax error.

Comment: query should be `$query = "select * from sfrole where email = '{$id}' LIMIT 1";`

Comment: base64 is not encryption. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: Because you need to escape the string before you run it in the query. Check out mysql_real_escape_string().

Comment: I also used like this ` $query = "select * from sfrole where email={'$id'} LIMIT 1";` but same problem

Comment: LIKE is a comparison not a function. LIKE '%something%'. However there is no need to use LIKE here. You're looking for a perfect match (albeit case insensitive) not a partial match.

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape the string before you run it in the query.

https://www.php.net/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

```
<?php
require_once("db.php");
$id="";
$emailrole="";
if($_GET){
    if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = base64_decode($_GET['id']);
    $query = "SELECT * FROM sfrole WHERE email LIKE '" . mysql_real_escape_string($id) . "' LIMIT 1";
    $qryy = mysql_query($query);
    $cnt = mysql_num_rows($qryy);
    if($cnt > 0){
        $emailrole = mysql_fetch_array($qryy);
    }else{
        exit();
    }
    }else{
        exit();
    }
}else{
    exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: It's base64 why you're using mysql_real_escape_string?

Comment: It was base64. You decoded it and assigned the decoded data to the variable id.

Comment: Sit It Only working when i do this `$query = "select * from sfrole where email like('malik.adeel@shakarganj.com.pk') LIMIT 1";`

Comment: While this is correct there is no need to use LIKE here; without including a character to find a partial match it may as well be =

Comment: See My Update for More Details

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
select * from sfrole where email = '$id' LIMIT 1
```

For what reason you use curly braces "{$id}"? I think if you want encription it's better to use md5 but it isn't good to encrypt emails. Imagine that you should send emails to users but before sending you should decrypt them, it's not usable and has worse performance.

UPDATE:

Sorry, now I understand that you don't save it in base64 in DB :-) Try to compare input value and DB value to understand what happens.

Comment: "{$var}" means you don't have to do the "string here".$var."annoying concatenation thing": works with arrays too :), "hello {$array['blah']}"

Comment: You use curly braces to include variables and it's completely valid. The curly braces would not be included in the final query.

Comment: user1820339, try to compare value in DB and input value, maybe there's a space or something other in one of the values.

Comment: You need curly braces when you have a word character after it, e.g. where $object->noun exists, "I have two {$object->noun}s." will work but "I have two $object->nouns." will be parsed wrong as $object->nouns wasn't the variable you were looking for. I use "annoying concatenation thing" though, far easier to read and for other coders to read your code.

Comment: Understand, but for what reason they are in this sample? Everyting will work without them. Here's real example of the braces "{$square->width}00" or Dale's "hello {$array['blah']}".

Answer (score 0):

your select query is incorrect.please change it. you also check your query by using echo before query.
you should use this

```
$query="select * from sfrole where id='$id' and email LIKE 'example@gmail.com'  LIMIT 1";
```